# Are there any online math games similar to CheckIO or CodeCombat?

Tags: education

There are several nice online programming games where you need to solve problems in one place to unlock other places on the map.

Are you aware of similar games focussing on math problems? Or (even better) math problems combined with programming?

Comment: Do you know about project Euler? https://projecteuler.net/ It's not presented as a game, but a serie of challenges

Comment: It would be very difficult to programmatically check submitted proofs, so I don't think there is an online math game (unless it revolves around operations or multiple choice questions).

Comment: "Human Resource Machine" is a computer game with programming puzzles in a sequence of quite-constrained assembly-like languages. Some of the programming challenges are related to things in mathematics like the fibonacci sequence.